why wont the and in this while statement work?
i know this is kinda small, but ive been stuck on this for quite a while and it wont work. im trying to run the following while statement:
while xpos != x and ypos != y :
as seen in the code above, ive already tried using and which according to google is correct. ive also tried & but that didn't work either. its supposed to keep running until bolth position variables (xpos and ypos) reach their targets (x and y). however, it breaks the while loop when only one of them meets their target.

This is a logical error you want to use an or instead of an and. We should have some existing questions for this but I can't find them currently.

With and, the while stops when one of them is false. You want or so the while stops when both of them are false.

It also might be clearer to write while not (xpos == x and ypos == y):

You can skip the logical connective altogether and use a tuple: while (xpos, ypos) != (x, y): ...

Why does non-equality check of one variable against many values always return true? isn't quite on-point, but it is caused by the same underlying error. As there, De Morgan's rules explained is relevant.

...the C question Why is the && operator acting as || in this C code and vice versa? is on-point, insofar as it too is a case where it's two different variables on each side of the and.
